# How to upload files in HoloLens 2 from Windows Device Portal

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I want to upload files in HoloLens with Windows Device Portal. According to [the documentation on using the Windows Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal), I should be able to "Use the file explorer to browse, upload, and download files". Nevertheless, in the File Explorer section of Windows Device Portal, I can't see any option to upload files, but I can only browse or download files. Can anyone give a hint on how to upload files?

Comment: Can you show us show it looks once you are in the path  'FileExplorer/Documents?'

Answer (score 0):

> Nevertheless, in the File Explorer section of Windows Device Portal, I can't see any option to upload files, but I can only browse or download files

Please aware that not all folders have the file uploading permission, not sure which folder path you are accessing. As a test, if you go to the Documents folder, normally you should see the Upload  button as below:

[image: Device Portal]

If you really can't see the button, you can check the following things:

1. The HoloLens OS version and browser. We have ever seen the compatibility issue on several browsers running previous HoloLens OS version, I would suggest you trying Microsoft Edge and upgrading OS to the latest version. Check out this [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-release-notes#for-developers)
2. Policy Restriction on Device. Some group policy may impose restrictions on device, you may need to check with IT team in this case.